# Sidenav that only appears on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

So everyone by now understands the pain of responsive design and today I had to scratch my head for a few seconds as well.

So basically what I am trying to do is to get a regular div element (on desktop - it is a product filter) to appear in a sidenav (http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp) on mobile devices, to save some space.

I have been looking around for a few hours now but haven't found anything since. Could you guys help me out with this?

Edit 1: HTML source code added:

```
<div class="span4">
    <div class="vs-sidebox et-sidebox-categ clearfix ty-sidebox">
    <h2 class="vs-sidebox-title"><span>Filter</span> <span class="vs-title-toggle cm-combination visible-phone visible-tablet clearfix" id="sw_sidebox_79"><i class="ty-sidebox__icon-open ty-icon-down-open"></i> <i class="ty-sidebox__icon-hide ty-icon-up-open"></i></span></h2>
    <div class="vs-sidebox-body vs-toggle-body clearfix" id="sidebox_79">
        <!-- Inline script moved to the bottom of the page -->
        <div class="cm-product-filters" data-ca-base-url="http://xxxxxxx.com/koken-and-tafelen/onderweg/" data-ca-target-id="product_filters_*,products_search_*,category_products_*,product_features_*,breadcrumbs_*,currencies_*,languages_*,selected_filters_*" id="product_filters_79">
            <div class="ty-product-filters__wrapper">
                <div class="ty-product-filters__block">
                    <div class="ty-product-filters__switch cm-combination-filter_79_4 open cm-save-state cm-ss-reverse" id="sw_content_79_4">
                        <span class="ty-product-filters__title">Serie</span> <i class="ty-icon-right-open-thin vs-filter-closed"></i> <i class="ty-icon-down-open vs-filter-open"></i>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="ty-product-filters" id="content_79_4">
                        <li class="ty-product-filters__item-more">
                            <ul class="ty-product-filters__variants cm-filter-table" data-ca-clear-id="elm_search_clear_79_4" data-ca-empty-id="elm_search_empty_79_4" data-ca-input-id="elm_search_79_4" id="ranges_79_4" style="max-height: 20em;">
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="4" id="elm_checkbox_79_4_5593" name="product_filters[4]" type="checkbox" value="5593">Campus</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="4" id="elm_checkbox_79_4_5621" name="product_filters[4]" type="checkbox" value="5621">ToGo</label></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="ty-product-filters__no-items-found hidden" id="elm_search_empty_79_4">Geen items gevonden met dit zoekcriterium</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ty-product-filters__block">
                    <div class="ty-product-filters__switch cm-combination-filter_79_5 open cm-save-state cm-ss-reverse" id="sw_content_79_5">
                        <span class="ty-product-filters__title">Print</span> <i class="ty-icon-right-open-thin vs-filter-closed"></i> <i class="ty-icon-down-open vs-filter-open"></i>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="ty-product-filters" id="content_79_5">
                        <li>
                            <!-- Inline script moved to the bottom of the page -->
                            <div class="ty-product-filters__search">
                                <input autocomplete="off" class="cm-autocomplete-off ty-input-text-medium" id="elm_search_79_5" name="q" placeholder="Zoeken" type="text" value=""> <i class="ty-product-filters__search-icon ty-icon-cancel-circle hidden" id="elm_search_clear_79_5" title="Verwijder"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ty-product-filters__item-more">
                            <ul class="ty-product-filters__variants cm-filter-table" data-ca-clear-id="elm_search_clear_79_5" data-ca-empty-id="elm_search_empty_79_5" data-ca-input-id="elm_search_79_5" id="ranges_79_5" style="max-height: 20em;">
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5608" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5608">Animal Planet Giraffe</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5610" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5610">Animal Planet Haai</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5611" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5611">Animal Planet Panda</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5613" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5613">Animal Planet Tijger</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5612" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5612">Animal Planet Wolf</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5614" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5614">Finding Dory</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5615" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5615">Frozen Sisters Forever</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5618" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5618">My favourite horse</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5616" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5616">Paw Patrol</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5619" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5619">Spiderman</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5620" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5620">Star Wars</label></li>
                                <li class="cm-product-filters-checkbox-container ty-product-filters__group"><label><input class="cm-product-filters-checkbox" data-ca-filter-id="5" id="elm_checkbox_79_5_5617" name="product_filters[5]" type="checkbox" value="5617">Trolls</label></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="ty-product-filters__no-items-found hidden" id="elm_search_empty_79_5">Geen items gevonden met dit zoekcriterium</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ty-product-filters__tools clearfix">
                    <a class="ty-product-filters__reset-button cm-ajax cm-ajax-full-render cm-history reset-filters" data-ca-event="ce.filtersinit" data-ca-scroll=".ty-mainbox-title" data-ca-target-id="product_filters_*,products_search_*,category_products_*,product_features_*,breadcrumbs_*,currencies_*,languages_*,selected_filters_*" href="http://xxxxx.com/koken-and-tafelen/onderweg/" rel="nofollow"><i class="ty-icon-cw"></i> Herstel</a>
                </div>
            </div><!--product_filters_79-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add your HTML code?

Comment: Just use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Very easy to use, standardized, and has this functionality built in

Comment: @DelightedD0D then it would override certain functions we have allready built in, like certain styles and such. I have no other way than using what I have, and that is jQuery or just plain javascript.

Comment: @wscourge here you go

Comment: Then I would use media queries with your Css to hide and show the elects based on screen size. It's the same thing bootstrap does.

Comment: And on desktop, it is not nested in your sidenav, right? What is my point: does your filter have to be inside different HTML tag (parent) on desktop than on mobile?

Comment: @wscourge yes, otherwise it will be aligned wrong.

Comment: In that case, I would simply add it in both places and toggle their visibility depending on the screen width. Other solutions will require usage of javascript, as you cannot really mix up parents with css.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it uses ony css and html

```css
body{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
header{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#e2e2e2;
  height:70px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:10;
}

nav{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:70px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
/*=======Mobile Navigation==========*/
.menu {
  background: #ef4035;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 240px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
  outline: none;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
  height:60px;
}

.menu ul li a{
  width:100%;
  z-index:50;
  color:white;
  display:block;
  height:60px;
  font-size:1.4em;
  line-height:60px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:'DINNextLTW01-UltraLight_706122';
}

.menu ul li a:hover{
  font-size:1.5em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 65em) {
  .menu {
    visibility:hidden;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 65em) {
  #navbar-header{
    width:100%;
    float:none;
  }

  .navbar-brand{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }

  #navbar-header img{
    height:60px;
    width:auto;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:5px;
    display:block;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
  }

  .menu {
    width:230px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-230px, 0, 0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }

  .menu .smartphone-menu-trigger {
    width:50px;
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    background:#fd5f54;
  }

  .menu .smartphone-menu-trigger:before,
  .menu .smartphone-menu-trigger:after {
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  }

  .menu .smartphone-menu-trigger:after {
    top: 55%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  }

  .menu:focus {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  }

  .menu:focus .smartphone-menu-trigger {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav role="navigation">
        <div class="menu" tabindex="0">
          <div class="smartphone-menu-trigger"></div>
          <ul>
            <li tabindex="0"><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li tabindex="0"><a href="#about-section"><span>About</span></a></li>
            <li tabindex="0"><a href=""><span>Services</span></a></li>
            <li tabindex="0"><a href="#portfolio-section"><span>Projects</span></a></li>
            <li tabindex="0"><a href="#clients-section"><span>Clients</span></a></li>
            <li tabindex="0"><a href="#contact-section"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote for my needs sass mixin to handy control the responsiveness.
[[link]](https://github.com/devrafalko/SASS-Templates/blob/master/responsive-media-style-creator.scss)
If you use scss just add this mixin to your code and then:

```
#miDIV{
    @include media(small,andsmaller){
       //your properties for #myDIV elem for mobile devices
       position:fixed;
       top:0;
       left:0;
       height:100%;
       width:10vw;
    };
}
```

And here is the sample, resize the browser to see the effect [Codepen](http://codepen.io/devrafalko/pen/VmqoRE)